# Drawing meridians and parallels using basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

I'm bit stuck on this. I want to plot meridians and parallels on a map with the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# creates an object called map which can plot various things on different projections

plt.figure(figsize=(7,6))
map = Basemap(projection='cyl',llcrnrlat=50.,urcrnrlat=59.,\
        llcrnrlon=-7.5,urcrnrlon=3,resolution='l')

map.drawmapboundary()  
map.drawcoastlines()

# draw grid plots
map.drawparallels(np.arange(-7.0,2.0,1.0),labels=[1,0,0,0]) #longigtude
map.drawmeridians(np.arange(51.0,58.0,1.0),labels=[0,0,0,1]) #latitude 

# make image bigger:
plt.show()
```

[image]
The plot works fine, but no grid lines. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You meridians and parallels do not suite the area of interest. Your parallels have to be your meridians (you made a misprint in your code):

```
# draw grid plots
map.drawmeridians(np.arange(-7.0,2.0,1.0),labels=[1,0,0,0]) #longitudes
map.drawparallels(np.arange(51.0,58.0,1.0),labels=[0,0,0,1]) #latitudes
```

[image]